# Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build signed APK and it is not the first time I am doing this with the same project but this time it shows the following warnings.
And I cannot build the APK.

```
Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.    
API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'. 
API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'. 
API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.   
API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. 
API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.   
API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'. 
API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'. 
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer object()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer  
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer key(java.lang.String)' in program class org.json.JSONStringer 
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer endObject()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer   
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer array()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer   
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer endArray()' in program class org.json.JSONStringer    
com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer value(java.lang.Object)' in program class org.json.JSONStringer   
there were 6 unresolved references to program class members.    
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is'nt much information in the trace above.

You may use ***./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace --info --debug***.

This would give you more information on where the actual problem is.

Try a clean build as well using ***./gradlew clean***

Comment: It shows this warning 'com.google.firebase.database.util.JsonMapper: can't find referenced method 'org.json.JSONStringer key(java.lang.String)' in program class org.json.JSONStringer'

Comment: When I open the file org.json.jsonstringer. In that file, it shows the error 'cannot access org.json.jsonstringer.Scope'

Comment: Are you missing a dependency?